# What is the best way to store 1key - 3 value in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash

I have a situation where I have 3 different values for each key. I have to print the data like this:

```
K1 V1 V2 V3
K2 V1 V2 V3
…
Kn V1 V2 V3
```

Is there any alternate efficient & easier way to achieve this other that that listed below? I am thinking of 2 approaches:

1. Maintain 3 hashes for 3 different values for each key. 
   Iterate through one hash based on the key and get the values from other 2 hashes 
   and print it.

   ```
   Hash 1 - K1-->V1 ...
   Hash 2 - K1-->V2 ...
   Hash 3 - K1-->V3 ...
   ```
2. Maintain a single hash with key to reference to array of values. 
   Here I need to iterate and read only 1 hash.

   ```
   K1 --> Ref{V1,V2,V3}
   ```

#### EDIT1:

The main challenge is that, the values V1, V2, V3 are derived at different places and cannot be pushed together as the array. So if I make the hash value as a reference to array, I have to dereference it every time I want to add the next value.

E.g., I am in subroutine1 - I populated Hash1 - `K1-->[V1]`
I am in subroutine2 - I have to de-reference `[V1]`, then push `V2`. So now the hash 
becomes `K1-->[V1 V2]`, `V3` is added in another routine. `K1-->[V1 V2 V3]`

#### EDIT2:

Now I am facing another challenge. I have to sort the hash based on the `V3`.
Still is it feasible to store the hash with key and list reference?

`K1-->[V1 V2 V3]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It really depends on what you want to do with your data, although I can't imagine your option 1 being convenient for anything.

Use a hash of arrays if you are happy referring to your `V1`, `V2`, `V3` using indexes 0, 1, 2 or if you never really want to handle their values separately.

```
my %data;
$data{K1}[0] = V1;
$data{K1}[1] = V2;
$data{K1}[2] = V3;
```

or, of course

```
$data{K1} = [V1, V2, V3];
```

As an additional option, if your values mean something nameable you could use a hash of hashes, so

```
my %data;
$data{K1}{name} = V1;
$data{K1}{age} = V2;
$data{K1}{height} = V3;
```

or

```
$data{K1}{qw/ name age height /} = (V1, V2, V3);
```

Finally, if you never need access to the individual values, it would be fine to leave them as they are in the file, like this

```
my %data;
$data{K1} = "V1 V2 V3";
```

But as I said, the internal storage is mostly dependent on how you want to access your data, and you haven't told us about that.

---

**Edit**

Now that you say

> The main challenge is that, the values V1, V2, V3 are derived at
>   different places and cannot be pushed together as the array

I think perhaps the hash of hashes is more appropriate, but I wouldn't worry at all about dereferencing as it is an insignificant operation as far as execution time is concerned. But I wouldn't use `push` as that restricts you to adding the data in the correct order.

Depending which you prefer, you have the alternatives of

```
$data{K1}[2] = V3;
```

or

```
$data{K1}{height} = V3;
```

and clearly the latter is more readable.

---

**Edit 2**

As requested, to sort a hash of hashes by the third value (`height` in my example) you would write

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data = (
  K1 => { name => 'ABC', age => 99, height => 64 },
  K2 => { name => 'DEF', age => 12, height => 32 },
  K3 => { name => 'GHI', age => 56, height => 9 },
);

for (sort { $data{$a}{height} <=> $data{$b}{height} } keys %data) {
  printf "%s => %s %s %s\n", $_, @{$data{$_}}{qw/ name age height / };
}
```

or, if the data was stored as a hash of arrays

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data = (
  K1 => [ 'ABC', 99, 64 ],
  K2 => [ 'DEF', 12, 32 ],
  K3 => [ 'GHI', 56, 9 ],
);

for (sort { $data{$a}[2] <=> $data{$b}[2] } keys %data) {
  printf "%s => %s %s %s\n", $_, @{$data{$_}};
}
```

The **output** for both scripts is identical

```
K3 => GHI 56 9
K2 => DEF 12 32
K1 => ABC 99 64
```

Comment: +1, I liked your idea of hash of hashes. Can you just show an example of how I can sort based on 3rd value say `V3`? Please see my EDIT2

Comment: @cppcoder: I have added to my answer to demonstrate how to sort both a hash of hashes and a hash of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

The second approach (one array reference for each key) is:

1. In my experience, far more common,
2. Easier to maintain, since you only have one data structure floating around instead of three, and
3. More in line with [the DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself): "Every piece of knowledge must have a single, unambiguous, authoritative representation within a system."  Represent a key once, not three times.

Comment: Contrary to the implication, the first approach does not invalidate the DRY principle quoted in (3).

Comment: How so?  Each key is represented three times in three different hashes.

Comment: There are several ways of explaining it, but an example is the easiest: Your own link shows that DRY applies to relational databases, and the first approach is nothing more than the minimum requirements for a relational database.

Comment: Well, in that case the "keys" are no longer keys (in the sense of a primary key--or, more specifically, a column with a `unique` constraint).

Comment: @Borodin, Same as in any other relational database (e.g. a PostgreSQL table). It's because the id is not the "piece of knowledge", the relation itself is. Even though the same id is stored in three places, the relation is still stored using "a single, unambiguous, authoritative representation".

Answer (score 1):

In terms of readability/maintainability the second seems superior to me. The danger with the first is that you could end up with keys present in one hash but not the others. Also, if I came across the first approach, I'd have to think about it for a while, whereas the first seems "natural" (or a more common idiom, or more practical, or something else which means I'd understand it more readily).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's better to mantain only one data structure:

```
%data = ( K1=>[V1, V2, V3], ... );
```

You can use [Data::Dump](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aDump) for a fast view/debug of your data structure.

Answer (score 0):

The choice really depends on the usage pattern. Specifically, it depends on whether you use procedural program or object-oriented programming.

This is a philosophical difference, and it's unrelated to whether language-level classes and objects are used or not. Procedural programming is organised around work flow; procedures accesses and transforms whatever data it needs. OOP is organised around records of data; methods access and transform one particular record only.

The second approach is closely aligned with object-oriented programming. Object-oriented programming is by far the most common programming style in Perl, so the second approach is almost universally the preferred structure these days (even though it takes more memory).

But your edit implied you might be using a more a procedural approach. As you discovered, the first approach is more convenient for procedural programming. It was very commonly used when procedural programming was in vogue.

Take whatever suits your code's organisation best.

Comment: PS - so what if "I have to de-reference it every time I want to add the next value."

Comment: It makes me write additional lines and make the code complex.

Comment: @cppcoder, `while (...) { push @{ $x[++$i] }, get_val(); }` is no more lines than `while (...) { push @y, get_val(); }`. There's a slight increase in complexity which will probably be matched by an equal decrease in complexity later when you try to access the data.

Comment: @ikegami-Now I have another challenge. Please see EDIT2

Comment: @cppcode, 1) No such thing as a reference to a list. You are talking about a reference to an array. 2) Hashes can't be sorted. You can sort its keys, and yes, they can be sorted based on V3. `my @sorted_keys = sort { $a->[2] cmp $b->[2] } keys(%hash);`